# display: block is not working in opera browser

Tags: css

Hi can you see what is the problem with it.
Cuz everything shows correct in other browsers but in opera display:block problem with menu padding.

I updated opera to 11 version and now it is not working ;(

Here is my site http://www.mrblackscripts.3owl.com/
When you click on the menu link it just disappears links.

Comment: Opera 11 and FF 11 behave the same here, including the server errors. Or am I clicking on the wrong menu links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the first rule from `a.link:link` to simply `a.link`

Seems once you visit the link the `:visited` rule doesn't inherit from a.link:link.

If the above doesn't work you could add the block and margin properties into the `:visited` rule

```
a.link:visited{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 10pt;
 color: #999;
 width: 100px;
 height: 45px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 10px 0 0;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 line-height: 45px;
}
```

at the moment it doesn't do anything different so you could get rid of the `:visited` rule all together.

Comment: There is only as you can see menu ;)

Comment: O my god i can't believe i tried to fix and didn't even see this small problem. this works a.link great ;)